# Is there a workaround for setting java thread priority in Linux without having root privilege?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

I've been researching on the web to find a way to change the Java thread priority, and [it looks like that requires root privilege](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml).

My question is:

Is there a workaround for setting Java thread priority in Linux without having root privilege? My preferred JDK version is 8.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to do this?

Comment: @Makato. Because he might not be  running the application as root. Many organization has app specific functional id's.

Comment: I don't ever recall a time in which it was beneficial to my Java application to run as root @AshraffAliWahab.  This begs for explanation; something is going on with their runtime priorities but giving this application's threads higher priority doesn't seem *enough* like a good idea for me to accept this question on its face.

Comment: Let jaeyong answer why he need to set the priority. But I definitely would like to set up priority to my thread if I have multiple threads, one for production, one for consuming and one for cleanup. If the priority is not respected because of the underlying OS due to some condition, I like to know why and any other alternatives.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why I need to answer your question @Makoto. There are extremely diverse cases of java applications and some would need to adjust the thread priority for optimizing stuffs.

Comment: The only reason I'm asking is that it kind of smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175248).  Something is causing your application to not process data in time, so the solution is to increase the priority of the threads.  Something seems amiss.  I *could* be wrong, so I asked why you were doing it.  I can respect that you don't wish to answer my question, but since I don't quite understand the rationale or reason for yours, I hope you can respect my wishes to not answer until you clarify.